# It does not move from IOS, Android to form.action = result path?

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on moving to the result page after mobile payment. After completing the payment page, visit the redirection page first to navigate from the redirection page to the results page.

It works normally on the web, but it doesn't work on redirect pages in IOS and Android.

I'm using PHP and JavaScript.

```
$RESULTPATH = "/html/charge/pay_result.php"; 

function proceed() {
    opener.document.PayForm.No.value = "<?=$NO?>";
    opener.document.PayForm.Date.value = "<?=$Date?>";
    opener.document.PayForm.Reply_YN.value = "<?=$Reply_YN?>";
    opener.document.PayForm.action = "<?=$RESULTPATH?>";
    opener.document.PayForm.method = "post";
    opener.document.PayForm.target = "_self";
    opener.document.PayForm.submit();
}
```

I can't move to the result path of action.
Can't anyone help me?

Comment: Is `$RESULTPATH` a javascript or PHP variable? It's very unclear when seeing it in that context since it looks like you're defining it in JS (no PHP tags) but then you try and use it as a PHP variable.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson  Yes, resultpath is a php variable. Even if path is declared static directly, it is not moved.